# label color change on radio button click

Tags: css, ruby, simple-form

[image]

I'm using simple form for in rails with two radio buttons.
I want the radio buttons to be hidden and the label to change color when the radio button/label is checked. 
However the only way i can get this to work at the moment is if the radio button is visible, and when that is clicked, the label changes color.
The for and id are identical for the radio buttons so thats not the issue.
i'm not sure of the issue. thanks

```html
<div class="modal-flex">
        <%= f.radio_button "refund_#{invoice.id}", :credit_note, class: "radio-refund" %>
        <%= f.label "refund_#{invoice.id}_credit_note", t(".refund_credit_note"), class: "modal-options refund"%>
        <%= f.radio_button "refund_#{invoice.id}", :only, class: "radio-refund" %>
        <%= f.label "refund_#{invoice.id}_only", t(".refund_only"), class: "modal-options refund" %>
      </div>
```

```html
  input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    display: none;
  }

 input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    background-color: $color-gray
  }
```

Comment: We'd need the **output HTML & associated CSS**  ideally.

Answer (score 0):

fixed with some more scss. wrong syntax